# Como pegar uma constante ENUM pelo valor inteiro?

Tags: c#, enums

Tenho um Enum que representa os meses:

```
public enum Mes
{
    Janeiro,

    Fevereiro,

    Marco,

    ...
}
```

Como pegar a descrição do mês pelo valor inteiro? Ex.: Entrar com 12 e retornar *Dezembro*

Comment: Você poderia distribuir números associados á cada ENUM, é um dos melhores jeitos, ou você poderia usar o método ordinal() para acessar o número da constante, mas não é muito aconselhável.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deverá atribuir um número inteiro a cada mês, depois é só realizar a conversão.

```
public enum Mes
{
    Janeiro = 1,

    Fevereiro = 2,

    Marco = 3,

    Dezembro = 12
}

Mes mes = (Mes)12; //mes = Mes.Dezembro

Console.WriteLine(mes); //Dezembro
```

Veja funcionando em [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CMgwIT)

---

Um outro modo é utilizar um método que é responsável por pegar uma descrição do enum.
Por exemplo no mês de março, foi escrito como "marco" para retornar o nome escrito da forma correta adicione este método ao seu projeto:

```
/// <summary>
/// Método responsável por mostrar o user friendly names dos enums, apenas adicionando [Description("Nome Amigável")] e utilizar enum.GetDescription()
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value">enum</param>
/// <returns>String com o nome do enum</returns>
public static string GetDescription(this Enum value)
{
    Type type = value.GetType();
    string name = Enum.GetName(type, value);
    if (name != null)
    {
       FieldInfo field = type.GetField(name);
       if (field != null)
       {
           DescriptionAttribute attr = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) as DescriptionAttribute;
           if (attr != null)
           {
               return attr.Description;
           }
       }
    }
    return null;
}
```

E decore seu enum assim:

```
public enum Mes
{
    [Description("Janeiro")]
    Janeiro = 1,

    [Description("Fevereiro")]
    Fevereiro = 2,

    [Description("Março")]
    Marco = 3,

    [Description("Dezembro")]
    Dezembro = 12
}
```

Faça a chamada dessa forma:

```
Mes mes = (mes)3; //mes = Mes.Marco

ConsoleWriteLine(mes.GetDescription()); //Março
```

Espero que possa ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o pretendido será algo de estilo:

```
Mes mesEnum = "Janeiro".ToEnum<Mes>();
```

Essa situação pode ser verificada em outras discussões.

Eu encontrei um exemplo em inglês, mas podes verificar que encontras em Português, se procurares bem.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482/cast-int-to-enum-in-c-sharp